# Styling a nested XML element with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, adobe-indesign

I’m a print designer working on a travel guide that we recently started managing with XML-tagged content and XSLT styling. It mostly works, aside from this one small issue that has driven us to wit’s end! We have some sub-attraction listings that should appear as “child” listings that we can style differently in InDesign layout, and they’re noted in the XML by noting a value for their “parent” attraction in the MainAttraction tag.

My understanding is that we need the .XSL to notice whether there’s a value in the MainAttraction tags, and if there is, then to pull out the elements associated with that attraction to go under a different container tag so we can style them differently. I just haven’t had any luck writing syntax for this that works after doing some basic training and Googling around forums.

Here's what I'm experimenting with, which pulls in everything correctly except for sub-attractions (they're listed within the Attraction tags for their associated parent listing):

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <Cities>
        <xsl:for-each select="Root/City">
            <City>
                <City_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="City_Name"/>
                </City_Name>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <City_Stats>
                    <xsl:text>POP. </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Population"/>
                    <xsl:text>  ALT. </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Altitude"/>
                    <xsl:text>  MAP </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Map_Grid_Location"/>
                </City_Stats>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

                <Visitor_Info>

                    <Visitor_Center>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Visitor_Center"/><xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                    </Visitor_Center>

                    <Visitor_Information>

                        <xsl:value-of select="Visitor_Information"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Phone1)"/>
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(Phone2) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Phone2"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(Phone1) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>


                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Website1)"/>
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(Website2) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Website2"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="string-length(Website1) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>


                        </Visitor_Information>

                    </Visitor_Info>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

                <Description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
                </Description>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

                <Attractions>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Attraction"/>
                </Attractions>



            </City>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </Cities>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Attraction">

        <Attraction>

                    <Attraction_Title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Attraction_Title)"/>
                    </Attraction_Title>
                    <xsl:text>&#8212;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="Desc"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Admissions)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="string-length(Admissions) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Address)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Directions)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(Directions) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Phone)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(AltPhone) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(AltPhone)"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(Phone) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(WebAddress)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(WebAddress2) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(WebAddress2)"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(WebAddress) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Email)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(Email) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="string-length(SeeAlso) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>See </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(SeeAlso)"/>
                        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>

                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

        </Attraction>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SubAttraction">

        <SubAttraction>

            <xsl:if test="string-length(MainAttraction) &gt; 0">

                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>

                    <SubAttraction_Title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Attraction_Title)"/>
                    </SubAttraction_Title>
                    <xsl:text>&#8212;</xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="Desc"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>

                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Admissions)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="string-length(Admissions) &gt; 0">
                            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Address)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(Address) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Directions)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(Directions) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Phone)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(AltPhone) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(AltPhone)"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(Phone) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(WebAddress)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(WebAddress2) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text> or </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(WebAddress2)"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(WebAddress) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Email)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="string-length(Email) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>

                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            </xsl:if>

        </SubAttraction>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML INPUT SAMPLE** (note that the sub-attraction example, the Fredda Turner Durham Children's Museum, has a value in its Main Attraction tags and is nested within the attraction tags for its parent listing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Root>
    <City>
        <City_Name>MIDLAND</City_Name>
        <Region>BIG BEND COUNTRY</Region>
        <Population>127,598</Population>
        <Altitude>2,891</Altitude>
        <Map_Grid_Location>L-9/KK-4</Map_Grid_Location>
        <Visitor_Center>Midland Visitors Center</Visitor_Center>                    <Visitor_Information>Midland Convention &amp; Visitors Bureau: Open 8 a.m.-5 p.m. Mon.-Sat. 109 N Main St. 800/624-6435.</Visitor_Information><Address>1406 W. I-20 (Exit 136).</Address><Hours>Open 9 a.m.-5 p.m. Mon.-Sat.</Hours><Phone1>432/683-2882</Phone1><Phone2>800/624-6435</Phone2><Website1>&lt;a href="http://www.visitmidlandtexas.com" &gt;www.visitmidlandtexas.com&lt;/a&gt;</Website1><Website2></Website2><Email></Email>
        <CityId>MIDLAND</CityId>
        <Description>Description text goes here.</Description>

        <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Haley Library &amp; History Center</Attraction_Title>
            <Desc>Description text goes here. </Desc>
            <Admissions>Donations accepted.</Admissions>
            <Hours>Open 9 a.m.-5 p.m. Mon.-Fri.</Hours>
            <Address>1805 W. Indiana Ave.</Address>
            <Directions></Directions>
            <Phone>432/682-5785</Phone>
            <AltPhone></AltPhone>
            <WebAddress></WebAddress>
            <WebAddress2></WebAddress2>
            <Email></Email>
            <SeeAlso></SeeAlso>
            <MainAttraction></MainAttraction>
        </Attraction>

        <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>I-20 Wildlife Preserve &amp; Jenna Welch Nature Study Center</Attraction_Title>
            <Desc>Description text goes here.</Desc>
            <Admissions></Admissions>
            <Hours>Open dusk–dawn daily.</Hours>
            <Address>2201 S. Midland Dr.</Address>
            <Phone>432/853-9453</Phone>
            <AltPhone></AltPhone>
            <WebAddress>www.i20wildlifepreserve.org</WebAddress>
            <WebAddress2></WebAddress2>
            <Email></Email>
            <SeeAlso></SeeAlso>
            <MainAttraction></MainAttraction>
        </Attraction>

        <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Museum of the Southwest</Attraction_Title>
            <Desc>Description text goes here.</Desc>
            <Admissions>Admission charged.</Admissions>
            <Hours>Open 10 a.m.-5 p.m. Tue.-Sat. and 2-5 p.m. Sun.</Hours>
            <Address>1705 W. Missouri.</Address>
            <Directions></Directions>
            <Phone>432/683-2882</Phone>
            <AltPhone></AltPhone>
            <WebAddress>www.museumsw.org</WebAddress>
            <WebAddress2></WebAddress2>
            <Email></Email>
            <SeeAlso></SeeAlso>
            <MainAttraction></MainAttraction>

                <Attraction>
                    <Attraction_Title>Fredda Turner Durham Children's Museum</Attraction_Title>
                    <Desc>Description text goes here.</Desc>
                    <Admissions>Admission charge.</Admissions>
                    <Hours>Open 10 a.m.-5 p.m. Tue.-Sat. and 2-5 p.m. Sun. Free admission on Sundays.</Hours>
                    <Address></Address><Directions></Directions><Phone>432/683-2882</Phone><AltPhone></AltPhone><WebAddress></WebAddress><WebAddress2></WebAddress2><Email></Email><SeeAlso></SeeAlso><MainAttraction>Museum of the Southwest</MainAttraction>

            </Attraction>

        </Attraction>

    </City>

</Root>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT** (the sub-attraction doesn't display)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Cities>
   <City>
      <City_Name>MIDLAND</City_Name>
      <City_Stats>POP. 127,598  ALT. 2,891  MAP L-9/KK-4</City_Stats>
      <Visitor_Info>
         <Visitor_Center>Midland Visitors Center:</Visitor_Center>
         <Visitor_Information>Midland Convention &amp; Visitors Bureau: Open 8 a.m.-5 p.m. Mon.-Sat. 109 N Main St. 800/624-6435. 1406 W. I-20 (Exit 136). 432/683-2882 or 800/624-6435. &lt;a href="http://www.visitmidlandtexas.com" &gt;www.visitmidlandtexas.com&lt;/a&gt;.</Visitor_Information>
      </Visitor_Info>
      <Description>Description text goes here.</Description>
      <Attractions>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Haley Library &amp; History Center</Attraction_Title>
            —Description text goes here.  Donations accepted.. 1805 W. Indiana Ave.. 432/682-5785.
         </Attraction>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>I-20 Wildlife Preserve &amp; Jenna Welch Nature Study Center</Attraction_Title>
            —Description text goes here. 2201 S. Midland Dr.. 432/853-9453. www.i20wildlifepreserve.org.
         </Attraction>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Museum of the Southwest</Attraction_Title>
            —Description text goes here. Admission charged.. 1705 W. Missouri.. 432/683-2882. www.museumsw.org.
         </Attraction>
      </Attractions>
   </City>
</Cities>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT** (the sub-attraction displays and had its own container tags)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Cities>
   <City>
      <City_Name>MIDLAND</City_Name>
      <City_Stats>POP. 127,598  ALT. 2,891  MAP L-9/KK-4</City_Stats>
      <Visitor_Info>
         <Visitor_Center>Midland Visitors Center:</Visitor_Center>
         <Visitor_Information>Midland Convention &amp; Visitors Bureau: Open 8 a.m.-5 p.m. Mon.-Sat. 109 N Main St. 800/624-6435. 1406 W. I-20 (Exit 136). 432/683-2882 or 800/624-6435. &lt;a href="http://www.visitmidlandtexas.com" &gt;www.visitmidlandtexas.com&lt;/a&gt;.</Visitor_Information>
      </Visitor_Info>
      <Description>Description text goes here.</Description>
      <Attractions>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Haley Library &amp; History Center</Attraction_Title>
            —Description text goes here.  Donations accepted.. 1805 W. Indiana Ave.. 432/682-5785.
         </Attraction>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>I-20 Wildlife Preserve &amp; Jenna Welch Nature Study Center</Attraction_Title>—Description text goes here. 2201 S. Midland Dr.. 432/853-9453. www.i20wildlifepreserve.org.
         </Attraction>
         <Attraction>
            <Attraction_Title>Museum of the Southwest</Attraction_Title>—Description text goes here. Admission charged.. 1705 W. Missouri.. 432/683-2882. www.museumsw.org.
         </Attraction>
         <SubAttraction>
            <SubAttraction_Title>Fredda Turner Durham Children's Museum</SubAttraction_Title>—Description text goes here. Admission charge.. 432/683-2882.
         </SubAttraction>
     </Attractions>
  </City>
</Cities>
```

So what do I do here to make it so sub-attractions (attractions with a value int he MainAttraction field) can get pulled into new container tags? I understand that we want to create a new template for SubAttractions, but I don't know how to get only the desired elements into it. I'd greatly appreciate help in finding something to plug in here if it's not too difficult for someone more experienced.

[Original post has been edited to provide more useful info.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
<xsl:template match="SubAttraction">
```

won't match anything because there are no SubAttraction nodes in the input xml.

To get the match you'll need to change that to

```
<xsl:template match="Attraction[../../Attraction]">
```

then add

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Attraction"/>
```

before the line

```
</Attraction>
```

in your xsl:template match="Attraction" template.

Comment: This worked to help me style the tags I needed within the sub-attraction--thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Can I get a +1?

Answer (score 1):

> So what do I do here to make it so attractions with a MainAttraction
>   value get displayed, tagged and styled differently?

It depends on how different the styling needs to be. If it's *very* different, you'd probably want to use a different template to process each type, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="Attraction">
    <!-- code to process "regular" attraction -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attraction[string(MainAttraction)]">
    <!-- code to process "main" attraction -->
</xsl:template>
```

Otherwise you could use `xsl:choose` and/or `xsl:if` to branch between the two types within the same template.

---

### Edit:

The only difference I see in the way you handle the two types is the name of the containing element: either `Attraction` or `SubAttraction`.

If this observation is correct, I'd suggest you try it this way (minimized to only what's essential to the question):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Cities>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="City"/>
    </Cities>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="City">
    <City>
        <City_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="City_Name"/>
        </City_Name>
        <!-- more details here -->
        <Attractions>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Attraction"/>
        </Attractions>
    </City>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attraction">
    <xsl:variable name="tag">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string(MainAttraction)">SubAttraction</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Attraction</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
        <Attraction_Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Attraction_Title)"/>
        </Attraction_Title>
        <xsl:value-of select="Desc"/>
        <!-- more details here -->
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Attraction"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that unlike in your original question, you now show the sub-attraction as child of the main attraction. This requires another `xsl:apply-templates select="Attraction"` call from the context of the main attraction (as shown above).

Comment: From the description of the problem I would DEFINITELY use separate template rules here.

Comment: The styling will not be much different on what we call the sub-attraction vs. the main attraction...all we want is to add an indent before the sub-attraction name and change the font style of the name. I think the part where I'm really getting hung up is how to place the indent in front of the sub-attraction name and retag its name for styling based on having content in a MainAttraction tag farther down.

Comment: @Inks I am afraid I don't know what you mean (I see no font style or indent in your stylesheet). Why don't you edit your question and add the expected output of your example?

Comment: @Inks: ... *in InDesign layout* – you don't expand on that, but are you by any chance using a mapping from tags to Paragraph styles? In that case you'd simply map those not-so-main attractions to a predefined style with an indent built into it.

Comment: @Jongware that is correct, we map the XML tags to styles in InDesign and could apply the indent there later. However, before XSL transformation, the sub-attractions have the same tags as the main attractions, so there's no way for us to isolate only the sub-attractions for different styling. The only difference is that sub-attractions have a value in the MainAttraction tags. And at the moment, sub-attractions aren't appearing in our otherwise working output at all, for some reason I can't determine.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've added a link to a PDF that shows what the output of all this text is. Most of the indents/styling are handled in InDesign, but since the sub-attractions have the same tags as the main attractions before XSLT, I'm looking for a way to isolate the sub-attraction elements.

Comment: @Inks I meant the output of the XSL transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Derp. Of course, sorry about that--an example is now included.

Comment: @Inks I am afraid this is not much help either, because now we have the output, but not the input.  I am looking for a way to correlate between the two - IOW, what exactly is the stylesheet supposed to do.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry about that. I've reworked the information provided to be a bit more clear and consistent. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Brilliant--it works! Thank you so much for your time in helping us work out this issue. :)